# How do I check for nulls reliably in C#

Tags: c#, null, nullreferenceexception, equality, equals-operator

How do I check for nulls reliably in C#, including when overloading the operators `==` and `!=`?

```
class MyClass
{
    public static bool operator ==(MyClass a, MyClass b) { return false; }
    public static bool operator !=(MyClass a, MyClass b) { return true; }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        MyClass x = new MyClass();
        MyClass y = null;
        if (x != null) { System.Console.WriteLine(x.ToString()); }
        // Next line throws a NullReferenceException
        if (y != null) { System.Console.WriteLine(y.ToString()); }
    }
}
```

I know the following options are available:

- `x != null` Not reliable when overloading operators.
- `null != x` Not reliable when overloading operators.
- `(x ?? null) != null` The type still is `MyClass`, so it isn't reliable when overloading operators.
- `object.ReferenceEquals(x, null)` Should be ok.
- `x.Equals(null)` Won't work (of course, since we call a method on `x`, which can be `null`)
- `object o = x; o != null` should use `object`'s `operator !=`, so it should work.
- Something else?

So, which method is the best in terms of reliability, speed, readbility, and which is the most idiomatic? Does Microsoft recommend any method in their documentation/coding standards/whatever?

Comment: I find `object.ReferenceEquals(x, null)` the best choice in a case like that.

Comment: Not on your list, but I would use `(object)x != (object)null` which will force the use of the overload `operator !=(object x, object y)` which is predefined in C# and simply compares two references (most probably implemented as two integer "addresses", so an integer equality check behind the scenes). Of course, in usual cases, you could cast only one side (one of the operands), that is either `(object)x != null` or `x != (object)null`; the compiler must still choose the predefined overload, not the user-defined one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the static [ReferenceEquals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx) method of System.Object.

That's the technically correct solution. What you should do however, is to let your supplier of said class know that it is a buggy piece of shit and you won't work with it. It should not be your responsibility to fix other peoples bugs. It's enough work to fix one's own bugs.

Comment: +1 for the "let your supplier of said class know that it is a buggy piece of shit and you won't work with it". However, I see one legitimate case of doing something that looks like this: defining an instance that behaves like floating-point numbers' `NaN`, i.e. it is `!=` to everithing, including itslef (but arguably, `NaN`'s behaviour is a buggy piece of shit).

Answer (score 2):

> Does Microsoft recommend any method in their documentation/coding standards/whatever?

Yes Microsoft does recommend, `ReferenceEquals`or casting to object before checking for null. otherwise `==` will be called recursively. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28VS.80%29.aspx) is what microsoft has to say.

> A common error in overloads of operator == is to use (a == b), (a == null), or (b == null) to check for reference equality. This instead results in a call to the overloaded operator ==, causing an infinite loop. Use ReferenceEquals or cast the type to Object, to avoid the loop.

By casting to object it means,

```
if(((object)yourObject) == null)
{}
```

Comment: I'm not asking how to test for equality when defining the `==` or `!=` operators, I'm asking how to test for nullity when using a class which overrides `==` and `!=`. My calls to `!=` are in the `Main()` method, so there isn't any recursive call possible. I'll change my example to make that clearer.

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron - `if (ReferenceEquals(null, y) == false) { System.Console.WriteLine(y.ToString()); }`

Comment: @NoOne You're still talking about how to check for nullity when defining the `operator ==`, but as I said in my previous comment, I'm concerned about **using** a (third-party) class which overrides the operators, not defining the operators themselves.